# login image url for login status

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

i have a login control ,it works perfectly,,and i put login status, i get a specific problem when i specify the login image URL for my login status ,,the login control can't redirect me to the default page even when iam the right person ,it even does not enter the logging  event in this case ,,when i remove the image URL every thing is okay, i wanna to use image url to clarify the status..

i note some thing:

when i enter the user name and password and click enter through keyboard i logout and the focus is on the login status control ,, when i click on the button every think is okay ,, what is the problem????

Comment: Can you show us some code? Also: what is the URL of your image?

Comment: it is just an image in a folder in my solution.

Comment: the problem appears when i set the login image url property for the login status control.

Comment: Can you install HttpWatch or something like this and see what'a going on? This will show you the status of each request and might shed some light on the problem..

Comment: what i find is when i reset login image URL property and use text instead ,,every thing is okay,but either i click enter from KB or click my login button ,but when set this property some thing goes wrong i can't login at all..

Comment: Please elaborate on "some thing goes wrong", we can't help unless we know at least full details of the problem. Did you try HttpWatch?

Comment: sorry my English is n't good as supposed,, i mean by this sentence that

Comment: when i set this property and click enter (Keyboard) ,,it enters the logging event then it enter logout event and the focus appears on the status control ,, this happens only when i use image for status control , when i use text this not happen ,, every thing is okay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method described here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/896760.aspx

Hopefully after you define the DefaultButton to the correct Login control submit button, the ENTER key will work as expected.

Comment: Cheers, though it's weird why it happens in the first place, glad there is such a workaround. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the image in a folder/location that does not require authentication/authorization.

Comment: please ,, can u explain more what do u means??

Comment: Try open that image from your browser. You will see it redirects to login page. This must not happen.

Comment: no this not happens with me it is just a PNG image ,,what i want is when the user login the login status image turn to be for example 1.PNG and when logout turns to be 2.PNG for example,,no problem at all with the logout image URL ,, the problem only appears with the login image url ,,it doesn't allow the user to login at all